# Downloading and Installing .IPA files for installed apps in non gailbreak devices (developing an appstore)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, app-store, ipa

I am going to develop an app-store app. The clients should be able to download the IPA files and install it directly to their device and replace it with old applications. Surely most of the device are non-gailbreak so surely I should support them too.

I had see some apps like TestFlight that do it for Ad-Hoc apps. They install some certificate and then install the app actually I do not know what they actually do and also how can I do it for apps that should be install in all devices.

Do some body know any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do it via ad hoc distribution. You can do it for around 100 devices only. If you want to install the in all devices either you will have to go to Apple Store or you will have to purchase Enterprise distribution account (which is to server the application with in the organisation).

The application like Test flight also allows to install the application on those devices whose UUIDs are registered in the uploaded provisional profile. It is not doing any magic. It just provides a way to install the binary over the air.

Comment: I do not want do it via ad-hoc provisioning(it was just an example) Actually as you said I want that all of our client be able to download new versions and install them on their devices.

Comment: If they are not internal to your organisation then there is no way to go directly. You must need to submit your application first to Apple Store.

Comment: If I publish them first to the app store, then can I download them and directly install them to the device from my own application as well?

Comment: No, you cant do it. Same binary can be installed in 5 different devices with same iTunes account credentials.

Comment: I think we are not in same page, The clients their-self have their own apple account. I just want to provide a way so that user can able to download the app from my app and install them on their device.

Comment: That you can always do. When you create the application on the store. It gives you identifier. Using this identifier, you can create the URL of the application. Now take this URL and open it in your application. It will navigate the user to Apple store application with your application page.

Comment: First, let me thanks for your quick replies. Yes, I am aware of this way. But I want that users be able to download it directly and install it directly, without going to app store application. Is it possible?

Comment: No. Definitely not possible. If you can do it, one can by paid application and can host on its own server. This removes significance of Apple eco system. 100% not possible.

Comment: OK. Thanks. So I need to a way so need to search for a way that any app can update itself. I will post a new question. Thank :)